# Order of execution of back to back JavaScript Promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

In the following code:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    asyncFunc1(resolve,reject);
})
    .then((result) => {
        // do then1 stuff
    })
    
    
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    asyncFunc2(resolve,reject);
})
    .then((result) => {
        // do then2 stuff
    })
```

Will `asyncFunc1()`'s `.then()` complete before `asyncFunc2()` is executed?

Or will both execute (nearly) simultaneously, and their `then()`s execute just whenever they happen to return?

If the second one does not wait for the first one, is there a way to make it do so other than moving `asyncFunc2()` into `asyncFunc1()`'s `.then()`?

Comment: "*Will asyncFunc1()'s .then() complete before asyncFunc2() is executed?*" does `asyncFunc1()` take less time to complete than `asyncFunc2()`? Given that the two are asynchronous, there is really no way to predict. Unless the functions aren't really async and take predictable amount of time.

Comment: But regardless (if the functions called are indeed async), the second doesn't wait for the first to resolve, so if you need the second to run second either move it into the first then, or use await instead.

Comment: "*Will `.then()` complete before …?*" - do you mean the `.then()` call itself, or the invocation of the callback that you passed to `then`?

Comment: "*If the second one does not wait for the first one*" - yes it won't, why would it? You've created two completely independent promise chains. "*is there a way to make it do so other than moving `asyncFunc2()` into `asyncFunc1()`'s `.then()`?*" - not really. There's `async`/`await`, but that basically does the same.

Comment: Can you show the definitions of `asyncFunc1()` and `asyncFunc2()`, please? Are they actually doing something asynchronous, such as a timeout? And the best practice would be to move the `new Promise` within those functions, so that they return a promise themselves, instead of taking two callbacks.

Comment: @ITgoldman That won't make the second one wait for the first one.

Comment: I think the answer here is pretty much what I suspected.  I would have to move Async2() into the then() of async1().  OK.  If I gotta, I gotta.  I had hoped there was an async/await solution, because I haven't gotten around to learning that yet and needed a reason to jump in.

Comment: @KWallace Yes there is an `async`/`await` solution, but you didn't ask for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both promises will execute (nearly) simultaneously, because that is exactly one of the strengths of Javascript: Due to its callback-based design, it can kick off and wait for many asynchronous functions (in the form of promises) in parallel, without the need for the developer to care about complex handling of threads or anything like that.

If you want to have `asyncFunc2` wait for the completion of `asyncFunc1`, it needs to be placed inside the [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)-block of `asyncFunc1`.

You can easily see and proof that by simulating two functions which take a defined time (using setTimeout), for example:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved at ' + new Date().toISOString());
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function resolveAfter3Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved at ' + new Date().toISOString());
    }, 3000);
  });
}

function execPromises() {
  console.log('calling at '  + new Date().toISOString());
  resolveAfter2Seconds().then(result => console.log(result));
  resolveAfter3Seconds().then(result => console.log(result));
}

execPromises();
```

You will see in the console output that the first one will finish 2 sec after starting the script, the other one 3 sec after starting the script (and not after 2 + 3 = 5 sec).

If you want to make `asyncFunc2` wait for `asyncFunc1` without the need for `then`, you can use the [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) keywords.

In my example, the function `execPromises` would then look like this (`asyncFunc2` executed *after* completion of `asyncFunc1`!):

```
async function execPromises() {
  console.log('calling at '  + new Date().toISOString());
  const resultA = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(resultA);
  const resultB = await resolveAfter3Seconds();
  console.log(resultB);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you chain thens?  .then().then()?  Will the first then() finish before the second one is executed?

Comment: @KWallace Yes. That's the semantics of `then`. The function passed to it is executed _after_ the promise finished successfully on which it has been called.